# Office js Word - Edit Properties in DocumentCreated Class

Tags: angular, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I'm currently trying to set or delete properties, after creating a new document in Word:

```
   Word.run(context => {
                const createdDoc = context.application.createDocument(file);
                context.load(createdDoc.properties.customProperties);
                createdDoc.properties.customProperties.add("Test", 42);

                return context
                  .sync()
                  .then(() => {
                    createdDoc.open();                
                  })
        });
```

This works fine on desktop. The browser version of office displays the following error:

[image]
Seems like this operation is not available in the browser version.
Did someone might found a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocumentCreated` class is not supported in browser  [More Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.documentcreated?view=word-js-preview%20)

From the above docs, you can see that the body of the `DocumentCreated` belongs to the `WordApiHiddenDocument`  [Additional Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/word/word-api-1.3-hidden-document-requirement-set?view=powerpoint-js-preview)

The `WordApiHiddenDocument` 1.3 is only supported in the desktop and mac's. Currently Due to the mechanism of the browser, we can't implement the `DocumentCreated` class. thanks!